# Is the story of Lord Satyanarayana mentioned in the Puranas?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, vrata, satyanarayana

I would like to know if there is any reference about the appearance/form of Satyanarayana and his story, not just the mention of his name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Lord satyanarayana avatar of Vishnu and mentioned in puranas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15071/3500)

Comment: my question is DIFFERENT . i am not asking about MENTION but about his swaoopa and whole story .

Comment: But your question is covered in that question.

Comment: ok if you want then you can delete it no problem  .

Comment: Skanda Purana is normally quoted for the stories. But I didn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

The mention to Lord SatyaNarayan is present in pratisarg parva inBhavishya Puran along with Katha(story of bhil, Sadhu merchant, king Tungdwaja etc.). It is also there in Sakanda puran.

Comment: can you please quote both

Comment: I don't have sources with me at the moment, so can't quote. I am sure a quick google search like 'bhavishya puran satyanarayan' etc. will lead to sources.

Comment: Cite the exact verse of Bhavishya Purana in order to meet the quality standards.

Answer (score 1):

It is said that Satyanarayana is simply the original form of Narayana worshipped. It is generally applicable for any deity within the Vishnu Tattva, according to some authorities. Others say that it is the worship of Maha Vishnu in the causal ocean. Here is a chapter from Satyanarayana Katha:

> Chapter 2:
>
> The Lord said "Oh Narad! Now I will tell you about the first person
>   who did this fast. In a place named Sunder Kashipur, there used to
>   live a very innocent brahmin. In hunger & thirst; he used to roam for
>   his daily bread. When the loving Lord saw the Brahmin in sorrow &
>   begging daily; he took disguise of an old Brahmin & asked him, "Oh
>   Dear!, why are you so sad. Please tell me all about your difficulties.
>   Is there any way I could help you out?"
>
> The Brahmin told the Lord, "I am a poor Brahmin & I roam daily for
>   bread. Do you know if there is any way to come out of all this
>   sorrow?"
>
> The Old Brahmin (ie. the Lord ) said "Lord Satyanarayanji grants all
>   the wishes of all the people. Dear Brahmin, that is why if you pray to
>   him & keep his fast you will overcome all your sorrow & get moksha."
>
> After telling him all the details of the prayer & the fast; the old
>   Brahmin ie. the Lord disappeared.
>
> The brahmin could not sleep that night. He kept thinking of the fast &
>   the prayer which the Lord had asked him to do. In the morning, he woke
>   up with the thought that anyhow he must do the prayer & went out for
>   his biksha. On that day the Brahmin got a lot of money from which he
>   bought all the necessary things for the prayer; called his family &
>   did Lord Satyanarayanji's prayer. By doing so, the Brahmin overcame
>   all his sorrows & became rich. From that time onwards, he used to do
>   the prayers every month without fail.
>
> In this way, whoever does Lord Satyanarayanji's prayer will get
>   moksha. Anyone on earth who does this prayer will be relieved from all
>   sorrows.
>
> When Narad Muni noticed that the people on earth were eager to know
>   about the other people who kept this fast; he narrated another story.
>
> The same Brahmin now a rich person used to do the prayer every month
>   without fail with his family. Once he was doing his prayer, a
>   wood-cutter passed from there. After keeping the bundle of wood
>   outside the brahmin's house, he went in for some water. The thirsty
>   wood-cutter saw the brahmin doing his prayers. He bowed down to the
>   Brahmin & asked him, "Oh Brahmin, what are you doing, please tell me
>   all about it." The Brahmin replied, "To grant all the wishes of
>   human-beings, this fast & prayer is useful. I have acquired all the
>   wealth & fame by doing this prayer of Lord Satyanarayanji." After
>   hearing about the prayer & drinking the water, the wood-cutter felt
>   happy, he ate the prasad & left for his house.
>
> Thinking of Lord Satyanarayanji in his mind, he said "Whatever today,
>   I get from selling the wood, I will also do this prayer." So thinking,
>   he kept the bundle of wood on his head & left home-wards. On the way
>   home he went roaming in Sunder Nagar for selling the wood. On that
>   day, he got four times more money than usual, for the wood. Feeling
>   happy, he went & bought all the things necessary for the prayers (ie.
>   ripe bananas, sugar, ghee, wheat flour, etc) & proceeded home-wards.
>   On reaching his house & after cleaning it, he called his family & did
>   the prayer with due respect.
>
> The reward of the fast was that, he became rich & had all the
>   pleasures of life on this earth & in the end of his life he went to
>   heaven.
>
> This chapter of Lord Satyanarayan Swami is over. All say "Shri
>   Satyanarayanji ki Jai".
>
> Satya means “truth” and Narayana means, “The highest being” so
>   Satyanarayan means “The highest being who is an embodiment of Truth”.

Read all the stories here - http://www.angelfire.com/pa3/payalvinod/sai.html

Comment: Its not true. Such kathas can be written by anyone.

Comment: And therefore its not true? Satyanarayana katha is also cited in the Skanda Purana but due to bad luck, can't find it. Prove to me its false.

Comment: yes if you quote from authentic texts then its fine

Comment: I will find you the site.

Answer (score 0):

Please see a recent post in Sanskrit Lovers group of Vj Laxmanan (on Facebook) which provides links to the original Sanskrit slokas found in Skanda Purana. Also, if we study the Sanskrit slokas 9 and 10 of chapter 1(see abv post), we find a beautiful description of the Lord by Narada, as seen in VaikuNTha. Translations of these verses in both Hindi (chapters 1 and 4) and Marathi (chps. 2, 3, and 5) are also given in the same links...

I was unable to find Hindi translations for missing chapters abv and likewise Marathi translations for the same missing chapters.

See link here https://www.facebook.com/groups/248857878598149/permalink/1104693416347920/

The brief English katha we commonly read in our temples misses these details that I have noted briefly in my post frm a couple days ago. These two slokas by Narada, praising Bhagavan, do provide a succinct description of the "swaroopa" of the Lord.

Comment: I m.not asking the sanskrit verses but actual katha from the purANa

Answer (score 0):

The Reva khanda Of Skanda purana mentions about Lord in Satyanarayana form. The exact story is mentioned there.

Comment: Add exact reference or shlokas from Reva Khanda of Skanda Purana.