# What is the story behind Satya Narayana form of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu

I have seen in temples Sathya Narayana pooja being performed during every full moon day. What's the story behind it?

Comment: Question already present - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15071/is-lord-satyanarayana-avatar-of-vishnu-and-mentioned-in-puranas

Comment: Pls. see below comment , your question is duplicate of the questions mentioned. If you think its duplicate  then do , close your question. Or you can also edit your question to make it completely different than the previous ones.I am just for time being closing the question as duplicate.

Comment: Well I'd close but answer given here was the primary focus of the question than previous!

Comment: Yes , its possible that the previous answers are not entirely covering the issue at all. But the question covers all the topics like what is the story , why this puja is performed , is this a avatara of vishnu etc. Anyway just a advice .. do search the site before deciding a question to check whether its already present .. this happens lots of times.

Comment: When I ask a question,  related questions already appear. But when related question doesn't relate to what I ask, I move forward only then.

Comment: Ok , yes as i already mentioned this can happen. But the core of the question should not be the same like in above case "Satyanarayana and story " these are core topics which are similar as yours , so its perfect match. I recommend exclusion of  the topics which are already covered in previous question and ask a completely new question , keeping the Satyanarayana as base .

Comment: Even if you face such a situation do make sure to explain your point more clearly in question and clearly state what exactly do you want showing that its not duplicate etc. . This will reduce the chances of question being duplicate , but make sure that  core of the enquiry is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is said that Satyanarayana is simply the original form of Narayana worshipped. It is generally applicable for any deity within the Vishnu Tattva, according to some authorities. Others say that it is the worship of Maha Vishnu in the causal ocean. Here is a chapter from Satyanarayana Katha:

> Chapter 2:
>
> The Lord said "Oh Narad! Now I will tell you about the first person
>   who did this fast. In a place named Sunder Kashipur, there used to
>   live a very innocent brahmin. In hunger & thirst; he used to roam for
>   his daily bread. When the loving Lord saw the Brahmin in sorrow &
>   begging daily; he took disguise of an old Brahmin & asked him, "Oh
>   Dear!, why are you so sad. Please tell me all about your difficulties.
>   Is there any way I could help you out?"
>
> The Brahmin told the Lord, "I am a poor Brahmin & I roam daily for
>   bread. Do you know if there is any way to come out of all this
>   sorrow?"
>
> The Old Brahmin (ie. the Lord ) said "Lord Satyanarayanji grants all
>   the wishes of all the people. Dear Brahmin, that is why if you pray to
>   him & keep his fast you will overcome all your sorrow & get moksha."
>
> After telling him all the details of the prayer & the fast; the old
>   Brahmin ie. the Lord disappeared.
>
> The brahmin could not sleep that night. He kept thinking of the fast &
>   the prayer which the Lord had asked him to do. In the morning, he woke
>   up with the thought that anyhow he must do the prayer & went out for
>   his biksha. On that day the Brahmin got a lot of money from which he
>   bought all the necessary things for the prayer; called his family &
>   did Lord Satyanarayanji's prayer. By doing so, the Brahmin overcame
>   all his sorrows & became rich. From that time onwards, he used to do
>   the prayers every month without fail.
>
> In this way, whoever does Lord Satyanarayanji's prayer will get
>   moksha. Anyone on earth who does this prayer will be relieved from all
>   sorrows.
>
> When Narad Muni noticed that the people on earth were eager to know
>   about the other people who kept this fast; he narrated another story.
>
> The same Brahmin now a rich person used to do the prayer every month
>   without fail with his family. Once he was doing his prayer, a
>   wood-cutter passed from there. After keeping the bundle of wood
>   outside the brahmin's house, he went in for some water. The thirsty
>   wood-cutter saw the brahmin doing his prayers. He bowed down to the
>   Brahmin & asked him, "Oh Brahmin, what are you doing, please tell me
>   all about it." The Brahmin replied, "To grant all the wishes of
>   human-beings, this fast & prayer is useful. I have acquired all the
>   wealth & fame by doing this prayer of Lord Satyanarayanji." After
>   hearing about the prayer & drinking the water, the wood-cutter felt
>   happy, he ate the prasad & left for his house.
>
> Thinking of Lord Satyanarayanji in his mind, he said "Whatever today,
>   I get from selling the wood, I will also do this prayer." So thinking,
>   he kept the bundle of wood on his head & left home-wards. On the way
>   home he went roaming in Sunder Nagar for selling the wood. On that
>   day, he got four times more money than usual, for the wood. Feeling
>   happy, he went & bought all the things necessary for the prayers (ie.
>   ripe bananas, sugar, ghee, wheat flour, etc) & proceeded home-wards.
>   On reaching his house & after cleaning it, he called his family & did
>   the prayer with due respect.
>
> The reward of the fast was that, he became rich & had all the
>   pleasures of life on this earth & in the end of his life he went to
>   heaven.
>
> This chapter of Lord Satyanarayan Swami is over. All say "Shri
>   Satyanarayanji ki Jai".

Satya means “truth” and Narayana means, “The highest being” so Satyanarayan means “The highest being who is an embodiment of Truth”.

Read all the stories here - http://www.angelfire.com/pa3/payalvinod/sai.html